# GCC and Clang different behaviors on constexpr constructor

Tags: c++, c++11

For this struct:

```
struct Wrapper {
    int value;

    constexpr explicit Wrapper(int v) noexcept : value(v) {}
    Wrapper(const Wrapper& that) noexcept : value(that.value) {}
};
```

And this function:

```
constexpr Wrapper makeWrapper(int v)
{
    return Wrapper(v);
}
```

The following code fails to compile for Clang (Apple LLVM version 7.3.0), but compiles fine for GCC (4.9+), both with `-Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic-errors`:

```
constexpr auto x = makeWrapper(123);
```

Clang complains that "non-constexpr constructor 'Wrapper' cannot be used in a constant expression." Which compiler is right?

Comment: No compiler at hand at the moment, what happens if you remove the copy constructor?

Comment: Repro with clang3.7 and gcc6.1, copyable MCVE [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d72a2d90f44bb0dc), fix for both compilers [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/759e633b484f83a8).

Comment: @Baum mit Augen  why not post an answer?

Comment: @JesperJuhl Because I cannot answer the question as I don't know which compiler is right. (Though I would have bet on clang.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Although the copy or move when returning `Wrapper` from `makeWrapper()` can be elided, it is required to exist with C++14. The existing copy constructor is non-`constexpr` and its existence inhibits creation of an implicit move constructor. As a result I think clang is right: you'd need to make the copy constructor a `constexpr`.

Note that with C++17 the code might become correct: there is a proposal to make copy-elision mandatory in some contexts: [P0135r0](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0135r0.html). However, it seems this change hasn't landed in the working paper, yet. It may land this week, though (thanks to @NicolBolas for pointing out that it isn't there, yet). I haven't seen an updated paper in the [mailing](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/#mailing2016-06).

Comment: I know you are in the C++ ISO Committee (WG21), Please, I want to ask: *"When do we say a function or a constructor is* ***accessible*** *?"* - because one of the requirements for copy-elision is "being accessible". Read the ending of [this](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.copy#32) paragraph

Comment: @WhiZTiM I think it means the function or constructor exists and has the required signature (I'm using "signature" loosely to mean everything about the the function including `constexpr`-ness and other stuff), but the compiler is free to choose whether really to use it. Not 100% sure though.

Comment: @WhiZTiM: _accessible_ just refers to a member being declared [possibly implicitly], isn't deleted, and that it can be called from the corresponding context based on the access specifier: the constructor could exist but be `private` or `protected` and the call be from outside the class. Look at 12.8 [class.copy] paragraph 30 which points at 11 [class.access]. Note, that the section you quoted only refers to copy/copy-elision part. The next part is the `constexpr`-ness: the copy constructor is accessible OK but it isn't `constexpr`.

Comment: @ZizhengTai, I doubt so. Because your definition implies that a `deleted` constructor is *accessible* which doesn't sound right in my opinion, I may be wrong though... That's why I am here to learn

Comment: @DietmarKühl: "*the working paper already contains the rules for mandated copy-elision*" N4594 doesn't seem to have changed the definition of `prvalue` compared to C++14. And 12.2 doesn't change any language about how temporaries are created. Also, according to [this trip report](https://botondballo.wordpress.com/2016/03/21/trip-report-c-standards-meeting-in-jacksonville-february-2016/), the vote to add it to C++ will happen in Oulu, this week.

Comment: @DietmarKühl, Ohh.. Okay, I think I understand now. Thanks!

Comment: @NicolBolas: I thought we had dragged that in earlier. It is quite possible that I'm wrong about that - I haven't checked whether it was in the vote. If it is meant to be done this week it is a bit worrisome that there is no revision of P0135r0 in the mailing... I just checked and I can't locate P0135 on the Kona or Jacksonville votes page, i.e., it seems it isn't there, yet.

Comment: @DietmarKühl Which means we can't rely on it being present in C++17...?

Comment: @ZizhengTai: we can't rely on anything being C++17 even if things _are_ already in the paper. However, with the change not being landed and no paper being there it might not even be discussed. Looking at the work schedule for the Core Working Group, there is an update (D0135r1; the "D" indicates that it is a late paper which didn't make it into the mailing for some reason) and it scheduled to be looked at this week by Core. Actually, it was discussed today and the discussion ended with "Ready for vote on Friday" so it looks good...

Comment: See also [CWG 2022](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0384r0.html#2022)

Answer (score 4):

Clang is correct. It works in g++ because it's automatically eliding the Copy constructor (RVO). if you pass `-fno-elide-constructors`. g++ will also complain.

The C++14 standard isn't clear about Copy-Elision in `constexpr` objects..

[[class.copy/32]](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.copy#32) ...*(partially reproduced here)*

> When the criteria for elision of a copy/move operation are met....  .... the selected constructor must be accessible even if the call is
>   elided.

Until we know the definition of `accessible`? We can assume g++ is also correct?

[dcl.constexpr/9](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.constexpr#9)

> A constexpr specifier used in an object declaration declares the
>   object as const. Such an object shall have literal type and shall be
>   initialized. If it is initialized by a constructor call, that call
>   shall be a constant expression ([expr.const]). Otherwise, or if a
>   constexpr specifier is used in a reference declaration, every
>   full-expression that appears in its initializer shall be a constant
>   expression.

[Dietmar Kuhl's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37932251/1621391) tells us what's ahead.

Demo:

```
struct Wrapper {
    int value;

    constexpr explicit Wrapper(int v) noexcept : value(v) {}
    Wrapper(const Wrapper& that) noexcept : value(that.value)  {}
};

constexpr Wrapper makeWrapper(int v)
{
    return Wrapper(v);
}

int main()
{
    constexpr auto x = makeWrapper(123);
}
```

Compile with

```
g++ -std=c++14 -Wall -pedantic -fno-elide-constructors main.cpp && ./a.out
```

See it [live here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/48972dbfd6f57ace)

Answer (score 3):

Both compilers are right.

The rules for `constexpr` functions and initialisers say that no non-`constexpr` function can be invoked.

The rules for copy elision say that it's unspecified whether the non-`constexpr` copy constructor gets invoked.

The only conclusion can be that it's unspecified whether the function and initialiser meet the requirements of `constexpr`. If they do, then the compiler must accept it. If they don't, then the compiler must diagnose the problem.