# C++17 make_optional constexpr-ness

Tags: c++, std, c++17

[This page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/make_optional) says that the `make_optional` function in C++17 returns a `constexpr optional<...>`. I think (I might be wrong though) this would require that `optional<T>` has a `constexpr` copy or move constructor. However, [this page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/optional) also says that's not the case.

I don't know how `make_optional` can be implemented as the C++1z draft currently stands. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37932066/gcc-and-clang-different-behaviors-on-constexpr-constructor) for clarification. Is there some workaround, or maybe it's just the standard draft/cppreference's mistake?

Comment: There is no question in this question.

Comment: @immibis Updated :)

Comment: cppreference didn't conjure that `constexpr` out of thin air, you know...

Comment: @T.C. Yes I do… but someone must have made a mistake somewhere…

Comment: @T.C. Turned out *I* made a mistake *here*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @Yakk and @T.C. for their explanations. I feel an example should make things clearer:

```
struct wrapper {
    int value;

    // non-explicit constexpr constructor
    constexpr wrapper(int v) noexcept : value(v) {}

    // non-constexpr copy & move constructors
    wrapper(const wrapper& that) noexcept : value(that.value) {}
    wrapper(wrapper&& that) noexcept : value(that.value) {}
};

constexpr wrapper make_wrapper(int v)
{
    return {v};
}

int main()
{
    constexpr auto x = make_wrapper(123);  // error! copy/move construction,
                                           // but no constexpr copy/move ctor

    constexpr int y = make_wrapper(123).value;  // ok
    static_assert(y == 123, "");                // passed
}
```

So `make_wrapper` does successfully return a `constexpr wrapper`; it's the copy/move construction (although usually elided by compilers) that prevents the code from compiling, since there is no `constexpr` copy/move constructor.

We can verify the `constexpr`-ness of the returned (temporary) `wrapper` object by using its member value to initialize a `constexpr` variable.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly construct return values in C++11 with `return {something};`  If there are any non-explicit ctors that are `constexpr` you can return it from a function.

Comment: I believe that's an illusion caused by copy-elision. Without copy-elision it won't compile: [gcc](https://godbolt.org/g/X3pTzv), [clang](https://godbolt.org/g/AiqxxV).

Comment: And as the answers in my linked post mentioned, even if the compiler carries out copy-elision, a `constexpr` copy/move constructor must still be accessible (even if it's eventually not used).

Comment: @ZizhengTai It's your own example's fault that it's making another copy. https://godbolt.org/g/jT7mHd Copy-list-initialization doesn't create temporaries, conceptual or otherwise.

Comment: @T.C. If I do not use the wrapper object what's the point of making it? `std::make_optional` is said to return a `constexpr std::optional`, in my (and your) examples `make_wrapper` **cannot** return a `constexpr Wrapper`.

Comment: @ZizhengTai In what universe does it return a `constexpr std::optional`? It returns a `std::optional`. It is a `constexpr` function template.

Comment: @T.C. Maybe I'm mistaken but definitely I'm confused...doesn't that mean if the argument passed to `make_optional` is a compile-time constant then the returned `optional` will also be one?

Comment: On the other hand, I wonder why didn't they introduce `std::optional::iterator` and `const_iterator`.

Comment: @T.C. *It's your own example's fault that it's making another copy.* Ah I see what you mean. The problem is not the `return`, but the `=`.